# How to Calculate Mode in SSRS

Tags: sql, reporting-services, statistics

Can someone please help?
I want to calculate Mode in SSRS for each of the reference numbers in Col A for the % values in Col B so that it can be displayed in Col C as a Mode value. Please note, Col C is a calculated expression in SSRS. Sorry, if it did not appear as clear due to displaying restrictions. 
Many thanks for your help in advance.

```
Ref (Col A):
A1
A1
A1
A1
A1
B1
B1
B1
C1
C1
C1
C1

Rate (Col B):
14.20%
14.20%
14.20%
13.50%
19.60%
0.00%
25.90%
25.90%
0.00%
25.00%
33.83%
33.83%

Mode (Col C):
14.20%
14.20%
14.20%
14.20%
14.20%
25.90%
25.90%
25.90%
33.83%
33.83%
33.83%
33.83%
```

Comment: Did you already see http://stackoverflow.com/q/1943437/2033717 ?

Comment: Hi Steve! Thanks for your reply. I struggled to understand it. Any simpler solution will be appreciated.

Comment: There isn't a simple solution. You have to do this either through SQL subqueries or custom code in the report.